# kafka listener container in spring boot with annotations does not consume message

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

Not sure if I am doing some thing wrong but I could not manage to make it work. Below is my code:

```
    public class EventsApp {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventsApp.class);

    @Value("${kafka.topic:test}")
    private String topic;

    @Value("${kafka.messageKey:si.key}")
    private String messageKey;

    @Value("${kafka.broker.address:localhost:9092}")
    private String brokerAddress;

    @Value("${kafka.zookeeper.connect:localhost:2181}")
    private String zookeeperConnect;


    /**
     * Main method, used to run the application.
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws UnknownHostException if the local host name could not be resolved into an address
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, Exception {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context
            = new SpringApplicationBuilder(EventsApp.class)
            .web(false)
            .run(args);

        MessageChannel toKafka = context.getBean("toKafka", MessageChannel.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("sending.."+toKafka.toString());
            toKafka.send(new GenericMessage<>("foo" + i));
        }

        Thread.sleep(115000);

        context.close();


        System.exit(0);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "baz", topics = "test",
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(String data, Acknowledgment ack) {
        System.out.println("----- "+data);
        ack.acknowledge();
    }

    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String>>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(1);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        return factory;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toKafka")
    @Bean
    public MessageHandler handler() throws Exception {
        KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> handler =
            new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<>(kafkaTemplate());
        handler.setTopicExpression(new LiteralExpression(this.topic));
        handler.setMessageKeyExpression(new LiteralExpression(this.messageKey));
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.brokerAddress);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }



    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.brokerAddress);
        //props.put("zookeeper.connect", this.zookeeperConnect);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "siTestGroup");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 100);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 15000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }


    @Bean
    public TopicCreator topicCreator() {
        return new TopicCreator(this.topic, this.zookeeperConnect);
    }

    public static class TopicCreator implements SmartLifecycle {

        private final String topic;

        private final String zkConnect;

        private volatile boolean running;

        public TopicCreator(String topic, String zkConnect) {
            this.topic = topic;
            this.zkConnect = zkConnect;
        }

        @Override
        public void start() {
            ZkUtils zkUtils = new ZkUtils(new ZkClient(this.zkConnect, 6000, 6000,
                ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$), null, false);
            try {
                AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils, topic, 1, 1, new Properties());
            }
            catch (TopicExistsException e) {
                // no-op
            }
            this.running = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void stop() {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isRunning() {
            return this.running;
        }

        @Override
        public int getPhase() {
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAutoStartup() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void stop(Runnable callback) {
            callback.run();
        }

    }
   }
```

While I am able to produce message. I am using spring boot version 1.4.0.RELEASE and spring-integration-kafka version 2.0.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

to the consumer config.

By default, kafka will start the consumer at the end of the topic.

If that doesn't work, turn on DEBUG logging to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Hi Gary, found the issue.
1. I was missing @EnableKafka annotation
2. There seems to be bug with spring-kafka 1.0.3.RELEASE. It works fine with 1.0.2.RELEASE but gives following error with 1.0.3:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MessageMethodArgumentResolver: method <init>()V not found
 at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$KafkaHandlerMethodFactoryAdapter.createDefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
........................

Comment: That's not a bug in spring-kafka, it's a [problem with Spring Framework 4.3.2](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14616); you can use Spring Framework 4.3.1 with 1.0.3 or wait for 4.3.3. Please don't put stack traces in comments - as you can see, it's unreadable - edit your question instead.